# Spring Boot maven jar couldn't run

Tags: java

My spring boot application could run with idea but  and could be packed with maven but the jar couldn't run !
here is some exception message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa131940]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

my pom.xml has plugins:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I use this command to pack:

```
mvn clean package
```

and use `java -jar target/security-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`  to run this .jar 
this application can be pack, but couldn't run.
how should i do to fix it?

Here is my hole pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cn.linhos</groupId>
    <artifactId>security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>security</name>
    <description>security project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is maven compile message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building security 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ security ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\ATTRACT\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ security ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 117 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ security ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 27 source files to D:\ATTRACT\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ security ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\ATTRACT\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ security ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ security ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ security ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\ATTRACT\target\security-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ security ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.857 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-30T11:57:58+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/273M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

wwith the Jackson2ObjectMapper‌​Builder ,I using a jpa to save time and get time form mysql like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="simulate_data")
public class SimulateData {
   ...
     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
     @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
     private Date  crawlingTime;
   ...
}
```

how should i do?

Comment: The stacktrace tells you that you pass an invalid argument to your Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder. Have you already looked into it?

Comment: add your complete pom.xml

Comment: As per exception you are missing jackson lib in your classpath

Comment: You might be using wrong library version on classpath for instantiation of `org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`

Comment: I post my  hole pom.xml in next answer. My application can be run with IDEA, but couldn't well with jar @ Sangam Belose

Comment: But it can be work when i run it  with IDEA， dose this is different that i just run it with IDEA and with a jar package? @Krishna Kuntala

Comment: Check whether you have multiple versions of same library in your pom.xml or is there any other library which is conflicting with the correct class. Sometimes this happens many times if you have multiple versions of library  because it depends on the sequence of classes loaded into JVM.

Comment: I have found the mistake : in application.yml , I use a spring:
  jackson:
    serialization: true
    date-format: HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS ! when i delete it , the jar will be run as normal. but it couldn't get a time String from web html. how should i alert my code? @Krishna Kuntala

Answer (score 1):

I have found where is the mistake!
I have using a jackson in application.yml like this:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization: true
    date-format: HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

I delete this code ,the jar  could be run as normal. 
But without this code ,I just get a number in web html instead of a time string.
how should i get a time String?

Comment: But i haven't fix my question. my web app just show me a Timestamp， not a time string. how should i alert jackson? @Krishna Kuntala